# Obtaining multiple plots of a given data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-ufunc

I have this data:

```
s_result = [{'time': array([  0. ,   0.1,   0.2, ..., 299.7, 299.8, 299.9]), 'I': array([10., 10., 10., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'S': array([60., 60., 60., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'M': array([40., 40., 40., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'R': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 1., 1.]), 'P1': array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ..., 19., 19., 19.]), 'D1': array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ..., 81., 81., 81.]), 'P2': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D2': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P3': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D3': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P4': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D4': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P5': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D5': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P6': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D6': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P7': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D7': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P8': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D8': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P9': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D9': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])}, {'time': array([  0. ,   0.1,   0.2, ..., 299.7, 299.8, 299.9]), 'I': array([10., 10., 10., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'S': array([60., 60., 60., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'M': array([40., 40., 40., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'R': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P1': array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ..., 20., 20., 20.]), 'D1': array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ..., 80., 80., 80.]), 'P2': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D2': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P3': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D3': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P4': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D4': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P5': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D5': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P6': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D6': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P7': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D7': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P8': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D8': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P9': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D9': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])}, {'time': array([  0. ,   0.1,   0.2, ..., 299.7, 299.8, 299.9]), 'I': array([10., 10., 10., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'S': array([60., 60., 60., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'M': array([40., 40., 40., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 'R': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P1': array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ..., 20., 20., 20.]), 'D1': array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ..., 80., 80., 80.]), 'P2': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D2': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P3': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D3': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P4': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D4': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P5': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D5': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P6': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D6': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P7': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D7': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P8': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D8': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'P9': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 'D9': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])}]
```

I intend to work on only `M` as follows:

```
for index in range(0, 3):
    x_stochastic = s_result[index]['M']
    x_stochastic=((s_result['M'][0]-s_result['M'][:])/s_result['M'][0])
    plt.plot(s_trajectory['time'],x_stochastic , 'r')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Monomer Conversion,X')
```

The expected outcome is 3 different trajectories as shown in the above data. But this is what got graphically:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get your code as provided to run. Furthermore in the data snipped you posted all three `M` Value series are indistinguishable.

I've taken the liberty to modify the data to

```
s_result = [{'time': np.array([0,100,200,300]), 
              'M': np.array([40,40,30,0])},
            {'time': np.array([0,100,200,300]), 
              'M': np.array([40,10,5,0])},
            ]
```

The corrected loop

```
for index in range(0, len(s_result)):
    x_stochastic = s_result[index]
    x_stochastic=((x_stochastic['M'][0]-x_stochastic['M'][:])/x_stochastic['M'][0])
    plt.plot(s_result[index]['time'],x_stochastic , 'r')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Monomer Conversion,X')
```

then produces two distinct traces as desired.

[image]